# Java 8 Executor callable passing thread as argument

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing, callable-object

I need some help running the process in multi-thread environment (java 8) in parallel to process quicker. Here is my use case.

1. Retrieve records from the database (large amount, millions of records) ex : select * from EMP where …..and MOD(PK,totalLoops -1) =currentLoop  LIMIT 10,000 (Haven’t decided the limit yet) – PostgreSQL DB
2. Make a connection to cloud platform, read JSON and then validate data from database to JSON keys and returns tvalidated or not
3. Update the database with the validation status for each recorded retrieved above.

The idea of retrieving the set of records from the database and run the process in parallel is by using MOD value and the thread ID will be replaced by “?” 
in the query. Ex MOD (id,ThreadID) = Thread -1

Q1 . The issue is, I am not able to pass the Thread ID as an argument to the Runnable or Callable. 
Q2. Can I also use stream and forEach for the ArrayList to call -  process.getGCPDataFromJSON(); I can overload this method.
 Is it possible to have a thread and streaming inside a thread and have multiple threads ?

```
     private int totalNumberOfThreads = 10;

Callable<String> callableTask = () -> {

            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Current time :: " + LocalDateTime.now());

   for (int i=0; i<10; i++{

           process.getGCPDataFromJSON(ArrayList queryDataList = 
        DataAccess.getInstance().getDataToProcess(i, totalNumberOfThreads));

   }
   return “Done”

    };

    //Executor service instance
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
     //2. execute individual tasks using submit() method
    Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

    for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
        executor.submit(callableTask);
        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return "Task Done:";
            }
        });
    }


    String result = executor.invokeAny(callables);
    System.out.println("result = " + result);

    //Shut down the executor service
    executor.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: Using thread Id is a bad idea, as you aren't guaranteed any particular value for it. If you want an ounce of control, you'll also need queue qualifier values you can control. I don't get what you're trying to ask in `forEach` part - you need to clarify that one.

Comment: Another thing here: if your `DataAccess::getDataToProcess` returns actual JDK array list, your app will likely run out of memory processing these millions of records you're talking about, just on the basis of loading that much data into memory and storing it there.

Comment: If I cannot access ThreadID any other alternative solution for need ? Create multiple threads and query the data based on a unique value so each process don't bump each other for querying.

Comment: Your describing a batch process, so consider looking at existing batch processing solutions/best practices.

Comment: You can say it as batch processing but trying to run those batches in parallel .

Comment: @ M. Pro - Regarding the streaming: queryDataList .stream.forEach( dataObj -> process.getGCPDataFromJSON(dataObj)) - can I sue this with in a thread. I think you already mentioned your concern of having that many records in memory. Any solution?

Comment: I have updated the original posting. It seems working for me